# How to migrate Relationships in CoreData with TransformationPolicy?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, data-migration

I need to break down my `FTRecord` model into two `FTRecord` and `FTEvent` models. Hence I couldn't just use the light-weight migration and needed to utilise a full fledged mapping.

[image]

1) First I have added a `model version 2` and adjusted the schema accordingly and added a new join relationship.
`FTRecord one-to-many--> FTEvents` and `FTEvent one-to-one-->FTRecord`

### [image]

2) I have added a Mapping class and made it point to my custom policy class (see below).
[image]

3) In the `FTEventTransformationPolicy : NSEntityMigrationPolicy` I have defined the function to create a UUID as key.

```
@interface FTEventTransformationPolicy : NSEntityMigrationPolicy

- (NSString*)createId;

@end

@implementation FTEventTransformationPolicy

-(NSString *)createId
{
    return [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
}

@end
```

4) The remaining properties of former `FTRecord` are bound to the `FTEvent` (which I don't show here). Now what gets really complicated is the implementation of

```
- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject *)sInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:
```

I am quite lost here. How do I create an instance of `FTEvent` for every `old FTRecord` and add that instance to the `new FTRecord`'s `events`?